# String Parsing a Time

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I need to obtain a time in the format of "07:30 am" (not case-sensitive). I'm reading a file which has this in the format "07:30am". Eventually I will be constructing a DateTime from this, so I just need to get this back with a space before the am/pm part.

I can detect the occurrence of the a or p using this:

```
if(startString.IndexOfAny("ap".ToCharArray()) != -1)
{

}
```

What's the best ways to do this? I'm guessing I will end up with two strings that can be concatenated with a space? Can Split be used with the above snippet to achieve this?

**UPDATE:**

I need to end up with a space in the DateTime between the minutes and the AM/PM and I do not want to use regular expressions. So far, nothing I've tried here gives me that...

The actual input I have to handle is in this format:

RecDate: "04/30/2012"

RecTime: "05:30am"

I need to create a new DateTime object from these with a space before the am/pm part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two easy choices:

1. Use RegEx to fix the formatting:

   string newTime = Regex.Replace(startString, @"(?<=[01]\d:[0-5]\d)(?=[ap]m)", " ");
2. Use DateTime.ParseExact to just import the time as-is:

   DateTime newValue = DateTime.ParseExact(
     startString, 
     "hh:mmtt", 
     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

I'm partial to the second approach.

You need to use the Invariant Culture because there is no separator defined between the `mm` and `tt` in the format.

Comment: No such signature for second method - seems I pass a provider; which is the correct one for US English? Also getting error for second argument: "identifier expected"?

Comment: @IrishChieftain `CultureInfo` implements `IFormatProvider`, so something like `new CultureInfo("en-US")` ought to do the trick.

Comment: Added the CultureInfo based on @phoog's comment, fixed the `\d`. I always seem to forget about C# string-escaping.

Comment: THanks RIchard, I'm going for option 2 using this: string startString = "04/28/2012" + " " + "07:30am"; still getting runtime error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: For a full date/time in that format, you would need the second argument to be "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mmtt".

Comment: Actually,  last line of option 2 keeps giving me a System.FormatException?

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using Regular Expression for this? ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.80).aspx ) should be an easy thing for a Regex-Wizard (which I'm not)